# passing vector from a c++ dll in python ctypes

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes

I have a .dll that was written in c++ with `extern "C"`, this function is called BOLHA and returns a double.

the problem is that BOLHA has a `vector<double>` in the argument.

```
extern "C" myDLL_API double BOLHA(vector<double> OI);
```

in fact due the `extern "C"` I believe that this vector turns into a pointer and so I tried to load the function as follows.

```
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("_DLL.dll")

func = mydll.BOLHA

func.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double)]
func.restype = c_double

returnarray = (c_double * 2)(0.047948, 0.005994)

func(returnarray)
```

but I get the following error.

```
[Error -529697949] Windows Error 0xE06D7363
```

Comment: `vector<double>` is not a `C` data type.

Comment: however when I use the extern "C" I think that the compiler is able to handle that on a C data type

Comment: That `vector` being passed can only be successfully used by a client that are 1) Using the same C++ compiler and version that built the DLL, 2) The client must compile their code with the same compiler options as the DLL, 3) Must use the same heap that the DLL uses.  In other words, you're highly restricted on which clients can actually use your BOLHA function.

Comment: If you are able to modify the DLL code, you may want to encapsulate the use of vector<> within a class, where you can create and get pointers from outside.

Comment: `extern "C"`  does not turn `std::vector` to a pointer - it just disables namemangling. You could try cython to access c++-code from python.

Comment: This is wrong. Either convert your function to only deal with *C* types, either create a *Python* module using *swig*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in fact due the extern "C" I believe that this vector turns into a pointer

This is wrong. there is no mechanism that makes this possible by default.
Your `BOLHA()` function needs to receive a `double*` and then convert it to `vector<double>` or just use the raw pointer.

If you want this to work with the `vector<double>` signature, you needs something to do the work of converting the pointer to a vector. `boost::python` can do that but that would require that the DLL you're working with would be a python module and not just any DLL.

if you have the function:

```
extern "C" myDLL_API double BOLHA(vector<double> OI);
```

you'll need to declare a new function:

```
extern "C" myDLL_API double BOLHA_raw(double* ptr, int size) {
    vector<double> v(ptr, ptr+size);
    return BOLHA(v);
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me some example how I could transform the raw pointer in the argument in a Vector inside the function?

Comment: added an edit that uses the iterators constructor. @PatrickMachado this is pretty basic stuff you could have looked up in any C++ reference.