# How to use std::vector in extern "C" function？

Tags: c++, python-3.x, ctypes, stdvector

I have a .dll that was written in c++ with extern "C", this function is called **add** and returns a double. I want transfer python's list to  c++'s array, and then transfer the array to c++'s vector, so that, I can indirectly use the `vector` data type.

In the **add.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

extern "C" double add(double *arr, int n);
extern "C" double add_raw(std::vector<double> vec);
```

In the **add.cpp**:

```
#include "add.h"

double add(double *arr, int n)
{
    std::vector<double> vec(arr, arr + n);
    return add_raw(vec);
}

double add_raw(std::vector<double> vec)
{
    double sum{};
    //here some algrothm developed by vector<double>!!!
    return sum;
}
```

In **add.cpp**'s code, I referred to the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49747364/14641812;

In the **test.py**:

```
import ctypes

my_dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libAddDll.dll")
my_dll.add.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.c_int]
my_dll.add.restype = ctypes.c_double
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myvec = (ctypes.c_double * len(mylist))(*mylist)
result = my_dll.add(myvec, len(mylist))
print(result)
```

But I get the following error：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\test\03cpp\c++\TestExternalCpp\Test\test1.py", line 11, in <module>
    my_dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./dlls/libAddDll.dll")
  File "D:\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "D:\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'F:\test\03cpp\c++20\TestExternalCpp\Test\dlls\libAddDll.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Python Version:Python 3.10.10
GCC Version: gcc version 13.1.0 (MinGW-W64)
How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: `add_raw()` shouldn't be marked as `extern "c"`, since it can't be bound for plain c code.

Comment: You cannot use extern "C" with C++ classes (like `std::vector`), because it means using C linkage (without name mangling etc. which is rquired for C++).

Comment: @wohlstad You certainly *can*. The debate is more around *should*. Dart FFI integrates with C++ and has examples in their documentation with `std::vector`. EDIT: In trying to find the link, I can't. Dart has maybe decided that doing that was indeed a bad idea. So, put my original comment in the past tense for now.

Comment: @sweenish I was not aware of this. But it's probably useful only in some corner cases. I mean I would usually expect a clean C interface when using extern "C".

Comment: On a side, you probably want to be passing `const double*, size_t`, and `const std::vector<double>&` respectively, to indicate that you're not modifying the data and to prevent copying the vector. Passing references is also identical to passing pointers at the ABI level, which would make it much easier to implement `add_raw` on the C side.

Comment: This is *not* a good idea!!! You enforce a needless copy of the data in the pointer variant. If you indeed need both I'd rather call the pointer variant from the vector one (`add(vector.data(), vector.size())`) or even more flexible you provide an iterator-based (template) solution called from both (that would then allow further standard containers as well).

Comment: For the C++ code I would recommend to do as the standard library when it comes to containers: Using iterators and templates. Then you can use it for any type of iterable container and not only `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of searching, the problem was solved by copying the three files **libgcc_s_seh-1.dll**, **libstdc++-6.dll**, and **libwinpthread-1.dll** from the GCC compiler to the directory where the **libAddDll.dll** file is located.

Answer (score 3):

> How to use std::vector in extern "C" function？

Simple answer is: You can't.

At least not if you want it to be used from C code.

You can't use C++ objects from C code, that's just not possible. What you *can* do is use an [*opaque data type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) (usually implemented as a pointer to a declared but not defined structure) and a set of functions that accept this data type. The functions are *declared* as `extern "C"` *if* built in C++, and are of course implemented in C++ so they can use the objects of the data type.

But in this case, perhaps the best solution is to not mix the C callable and the C++ callable APIs. Use `#ifdef __cplusplus` in your header files to separate the C API from the C++ API:

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
// C++ code
#include <vector>

double add_raw(std::vector<double> vec);

// Introduce the functions that can be used either in C or C++
extern "C"
{
#endif

// C or C++ code
double add(double *arr, size_t n);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}  // Close the extern "C" block
#endif

#endif // ADD_H
```

Comment: Nothing in the standard (see https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link) restricts the use of C++ classes as parameters in functions that have a C language linkage. However, the effects of this are largely implementation-defined. It's not the most portable practice, but if you're willing to settle on a specific compiler and understand the ABI, it is doable.

Comment: No `#else` – C++ code should be able to see the C overload as well...

Comment: @Aconcagua True, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fundamental problem:

C doesn't know about `std::vector` – it even doesn't know about templates and neither about namespaces. So any code containing scope resolution (`::`) or template instantiations (`SomeTemplate<SomeType>` or similar) won't compile in C. So

```
double add_raw(std::vector<double> vec)
```

is not a valid signature in C, and it is not (while legal) meaningful to provide such functions with C-linkage (i.e. applying `extern "C"` on them).

Additionally: C doesn't know about `extern "C"` either.

So you need to hide all of these C++ features away from a C compiler! You can so by relying on `__cplusplus` being defined:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
// so this is a C++ build!

// only include C++ headers within this section!
#include <vector>

double add/*_raw*/(std::vector<double>const& data);
//        ^^^^^^^^
// you now even could have an overload, if you wanted to...

extern "C"
#endif
double add(double const* data, size_t length);
```

Still constructing a `std::vector` from a data array requires the former *copying* the latter – this is inefficient and totally needless.

You might instead base the vector variant on the C array version instead (`add(vector.data(), vector.size())`) – or to remain fully flexible create an iterator or range based variant that would be fine for any other data type as well:

```
// add.h

#ifndef SOME_PREFIX_ADD_H_
#define SOME_PREFIX_ADD_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
// we won't even need C++ headers here...

template <typename Iterator>
double add(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    double result = 0;
    for(; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        result += *begin;
    }
}
// actually we would't even need that one, we could use
// std::accumulate or here even std::reduce instead...
// you might want to prefer internally:
//{
//    return std::accumulate(begin, end, 0.0);
//}

template <typename Container>
double add(Container& c)
{
    return add(c.begin(), c.end());
}
// this one is fine for std::vector, but actually for most of the other standard
// containers as well, apart from the associative ones

extern "C"
#endif
double add(double const* data, size_t length);
#endif
```

While a C++ compiler would be fine with having the implementation for in the header as well a C compiler must not see it, as it uses C++ features, so you need to provide the implementation in a separate source file:

```
// add.cpp

double add(double const* data, size_t length);
{
    return add(data, data + length); // calls the iterator template
}
```

Note about overloading: On compiling under the hoods C++ *'decorates'* function names with a prefix (mainly encoding function arguments) which makes overloads distinguishable one from another. C does not provide such decoration thus in C there are no overloads possible (actually still some minimal decoration exists comprising the calling convention; doesn't change anything about not supporting overloading). This means that you can in C++ have arbitrary number of decorated overloads (i.e. with C++ linkage) and additionally at most one undecorated one (i.e. with C linkage) – which is the case above, too (each template instantiation maps to its own decorated function).